# Dynamically change the Column size on ionic

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to dynamically change the Column size

```
<ion-col [size]="this.size" [size-xl]="this.size_xl" [size-md]="this.size_md" [size-sm]="this.size_sm" [size-xs]="this.size_xs">
```

but this error appears

> NG0303: Can’t bind to ‘size-xl’ since it isn’t a known property of
> ‘ion-col’.

**NOTE**

its just working on [size]=“this.size”

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`<ion-col [size]="size" [attr.size-xl]="size_xl" [attr.size-md]="size_md" [attr.size-sm]="size_sm" [attr.size-xs]="size_xs">`

Although there's probably no need to define all the sizes, you can probably just define a single place for logic that'll handle the default `size` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `this`. Just directly use the variable name. For example:

```
<ion-col [size]="size"></ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens since those values are not exposed. Try to rewrite like this:

```
<ion-col [size]="this.size" [sizeXl]="this.size_xl" [sizeMd]="this.size_md" [sizeSm]="this.size_sm" [sizeXs]="this.size_xs">
```

You can see those exposed if you watch in the library the file components.d.ts.